# Nbconvert fails to render slideshow inline equations

Tags: latex, ipython, equations

Using ipython nbconvert with the options --to slides --post serve my inline latex equations fail to render properly.
In the notebook, all is working fine, but in the slideshow, for an inline equation like $\tau$ I see

\(\tau\)

My python dist is up to date, and my ipython too. I just installed Mathjax locally but it didn't solve the problem. I also installed node (last version :0.9.14) but it isn't found and pandoc is used instead.

Any advice ?

Comment: It was working for me until I update to the last version of Firefox (32)

Comment: Probably has nothing to do with firefox, see [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6392)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that iPython team found a broken link and fixed the issue.